# When I selected a UITableViewCell and changed the background color the label then top got hidden

Tags: ios, ios6

I used the original UITableViewCell, and settled the `cell.selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor =[UIColor whiteColor]`.

When I select the cell, the `textlabel` was covered which means that only the white was showing.

When I selected another cell, the first `textLabel` was visible and the new one was covered.

Comment: most probably your label text color will be white and you feel like its hidden . set some different color as selected background color ,you would have a better idea what i am saying

Comment: It works at all kinds of devices except IOS6 , I the color of the textLable is settled black and I did`n changed it at everywher

Answer (score 0):

try this and you will get a better understanding of how things are working:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// change the background of your label to some other color here , like black 
}
```

if your label is visible now , then this most probably means somehow your label color is being set to white which shouldn't happen as you're cell color is white as well .

Comment: It works at all kinds of devices except IOS6 , I the color of the textLable is settled black and I did`n changed it at everywher

Comment: when you tap on the cell , your cell should highlight , make sure your label text color is different than the highlight color .

Comment: a screen shot would be very helpful here .

Comment: Thank you ,I`ve solved the problems. It`s something about the highlight. I prefer to show the screen shot but I don have enough reputation so I can`t upload an image.

Answer (score 0):

The color of the textLable is always black, it just because the color will be highlighted and make it invisible.